# Not able to use DAI's permit() function

Tags: erc-20, dai, erc-20-approve

I'm having trouble testing the permit() functionality from the DAI contract. I've read [the documentation](https://docs.makerdao.com/smart-contract-modules/dai-module/dai-detailed-documentation#3-key-mechanisms-and-concepts) and a couple of other resources, although, I got the contract code and deployed myself a copy of it on a local machine testnet and got no success trying to make use of it. I'm very confident I'm not using the signature right. What `v,r,s` values am I supposed to provide to my function? Because, to my understanding, I need already a Tx or a Message+Signature to get my `v,r,s` values. The lack of resources or practical examples is difficulting my progress because I'm not being able to figure out how exactly I should do it. Thus, I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: For those having the same problem as I was, this helped me out and I'm now able to do it: https://github.com/degensprotocol/degens-jslib/blob/master/PermitToken.js